# Add all Facebook Ads on page without creating Zap for each

Tags: zapier

I'm currently integrating Zapier with Facebook lead Ads and pushing the leads to a CRM. I'm creating a Zap for each Facebook Lead Ad. All is working great.

I'm trying though to make this process more efficient.

Instead of creating a Zap for each Facebook Lead Ad, can I (when a new one becomes available) set it that all Facebook Lead Ads on a page get Zapped and pushed up to the CRM without having to create a new Zap for each Facebook lead Ad?

Can this be done by just leaving the "form_name" out and only selecting the page?

Any ideas how make this process more efficient?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Good news, you can do exactly that! There are two trigger options: `page` and `form`. Only page is required- if you don't set a form, it'll trigger on all forms for that page. If you add new forms, they should be picked up automatically.